# User Input Date in DAX column in POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a *column* in Power BI to group the rows of that data on.
I want the column to output text based on a comparison of dates.

Example:
`projected = if(staticdate1 > dynamicdate, "XX", if(staticdate1 < dynamicdate && staticdate2 > dynamicdate, "YY", .... )`

The dynamicdate presumably would be a filter or slicer the user could click a date on, thus changing the output of the column, and the totals per output would also change.

Is this possible? I've tried `SELECTEDVALUE()` but that didn't work. I tried creating a "what-if" parameter and adding that to a static date, but that didn't change anything when I changed the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

That’s not possible since calculated columns are static and don’t recalculate on filter changes. This works with measures only.